# Unfixable BSOD: Unmountable Boot Volume

Tags: windows-10, bsod

So I received a new laptop (Toshiba Tecra,) installed my usual programs from my old machine. The programs are Steam (and several games,) Unity, and Visual Studio. The laptop quickly slowed down. Eventually, it stopped working entirely. I received a blue screen... I think. It was the normal shade of blue with white splotches everywhere, followed by a reboot. When booting up in safe mode, my account was corrupted. Something had deleted my User folder! After this reboot, the machine couldn’t even reach safe mode. I wiped the drive, installed Windows again, and reinstalled my programs. Now this worked for about a week. Now I receive the UNDMOUNTABLE_BOOT_VOLUME_ERROR. Bootrec cannot locate a Windows install, system restore cannot find a restore point, etc. I need some of the files, and there is no backup because it’s a new PC. Andy ideas? Let me know if need to clarify something.

Comment: first try chkdsk /f c: via bootable windows install DVD and then command prompt option.  The C: drive you see in windows may have another letter in this mode verify the drive you are chkdsk'ing has a windows folder on it.

Comment: I tried chkdsk, it found zero problems, I will check the Windows folder when I can.

Comment: chkdsk /R c:\    This will take hours, but it will locate bad sectors.

Comment: Chkdsk /r /c: skip output a little and it “found no problems” but “failed to transfer loopggedt messages to event log with status 50.”